# Add to cart url do not work

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I have generated an add to cart url on the frontend, but it do not seem to work. When I click on the link, I get the "You have no items in your shopping cart." page.

I have got this add to cart url from Magento: http://test.com/magento2/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tYWdlbnRvMi8,/product/7/

And here is the code how I created the url:

```
$id = 7; 

$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productHelper = $om->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

$cartHelper = $om->get('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');

echo $cartHelper->getAddUrl($productHelper->load($id));
```

Comment: does the product with id 7 exist ?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
$id = 7; 

$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productHelper = $om->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

$listBlock = $om->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');

echo $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($productHelper->load($id));
```

It helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work. I have got the same result.